# How can I change the title of the Contact Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, contact-us

I am facing an issue regarding change Title on contact page in Magento 2.

I have extend the template

`app/design/frontend/Mgs/child_theme_name/Magento_Contact/view/froentend/layout/contact_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

But Doesn,t seem any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please Check Below Step :-**

1. Go to your Magento store root folder.
2. You need open the `contact_index_index.xml` file to edit.
3. The file is stored under the `app\design\frontendMgs\child_theme_name\Magento_Contact\layout` folder.

**Add This Code In `contact_index_index.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title> //Add Your Title Here.
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="contact.us.wrapper" htmlClass="row" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                <container name="contact.us.form.wrapper" htmlClass="col-md-6" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                    <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                        <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="contact.us.googlemap.wrapper" htmlClass="col-md-6" htmlTag="div" after="contact.us.form.wrapper">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="contact.us.googlemap" template="Magento_Contact::map.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body> </page>
```

**If above code does not work for you then do following.**

This is a function under `vendor/magento/module-contact/Block/ContactForm.php`

**It contains the following code:**

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Contact Form'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have extended as you suggested and clear all the cache but still no success.

Comment: check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks For quickly response but still no success.

I have search the title of contact page in my folder it found on 
    vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Form/Register.php
If i change it from there it will updated on register page also

The function which do this 

protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Create New Customer Account'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

Comment: https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-how-to-edit-contact-us-page-title/ check this

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks it worked, but i added the method in core vendor class i.e `vendor/magento/module-contact/Block/ContactForm.php`.

Comment: How to override in child theme

Comment: override block in your custom module

Comment: Thanks for your all help will you provide any link about extend block in custom module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97368/discussion-between-urocks-and-rk-rathod).